# How to calculate the greater value of the average between has_many association in rails 3

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in rails,

I Have a Profile table and profile history table. Profile has many profile history.
Profile table has 
**id and current_count column** and profile history has **profile_id, and count** column

i want to calculate all the profiles which have current_count greater than the average of the count value of the respective profile history

How can i achieve this in rails 3.

Comment: What kinds of things have you tried?

Comment: @JustinWood i have tried something like Profile.includes(:profile_histories)
    .select('profiles.*, profile_histories.*, (AVG(profile_histories.count) - profiles.current_count)')
    .group('profile_histories.profile_id')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate sql query is

```
SELECT p.id, MIN(current_count), AVG(ph.count)  
FROM profiles p
INNER JOIN profile_histories ph on p.id=ph.profile_id
GROUP BY ph.profile_id, p.id
HAVING MIN(current_count) > AVG(ph.count)
```

Lets construct the rails way:

```
Profile.joins(:profile_histories)
  .select('profiles.id, MIN(profiles.current_count), AVG(profile_histories.count)')
  .group('profile_histories.profile_id, profiles.id')
  .having('MIN(profiles.current_count) > AVG(profile_histories.count)')
```